# Understanding Why (or Why Not) a T-Test Require Normally Distributed Data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, convergence, normality-assumption

This is a concept that I have always struggled to understand: We can write the formula for a  Two Sampled T- Test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test) to compare the sample averages from two populations as follows:

$$ t = \frac{\bar{x}_1 - \bar{x}_2}{\sqrt{\frac{(n_1-1)s_1^2 + (n_2-1)s_2^2}{n_1 + n_2 - 2}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}}} $$

**In university, we are always told that for the results of this test to be valid, the distribution of both samples collected MUST be Normally Distributed - yet we are never told why exactly this is. After much thinking and consideration, I think that if the both the sizes of both samples are large, this Normally Distributed condition is not required.**

Below is my logic to demonstrate why this is not the case for a specific example where $n_1 = n_2$ and $s_1 = s_2$.

**Part 1:** First, take the numerator of above term and divide by $ \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} $. Using the Central Limit Theorem, this modified numerator is now (asymptotically) Normally Distributed regardless of the distributions of $x_1$ and $x_2$:

$$ \frac{\bar{x}_1 - \bar{x}_2}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1) $$

**Part 2:** Since we divided the numerator by $ \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} $ , we also have to divide the denominator by $ \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} $.

Using some algebra, we can write the denominator as:

$$ \sqrt{\frac{(n-1)s^2 + (n-1)s^2}{2n - 2}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}} = \sqrt{2} \cdot \left(\frac{s}{\sigma}\right) $$

Now we proceed to divide the above term by $ \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} $ :

$$ \frac{\sqrt{2} \cdot \left(\frac{s}{\sigma}\right)}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} = \frac{s}{\sigma} $$

Now, using Moment Generating Functions, we can show that the following is asymptotically true (https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/26/26.3) regardless of any underlying distribution:

$$(n-1)\frac{S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-1}$$

**Part 3:** And finally, when we divide the results from **Part 1** and **Part 2** ([A normal divided by the $\sqrt{\chi^2(s)/s}$ gives you a t-distribution -- proof](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151854/a-normal-divided-by-the-sqrt-chi2s-s-gives-you-a-t-distribution-proof)), this results into a T-Distribution:

$$ \frac{\text{N}(0,1)}{\sqrt{\chi^2_{n-1}/(n-1)}} \sim \text{T-distribution}_{n-1} $$

Therefore, we have shown that regardless of the distribution for any two samples, provided the sizes of both samples are large enough - the T-Test DOES NOT require both of these samples to be Normally Distributed.

For simplicity sake, I did this for $n_1 = n_2$ and $s_1 = s_2$, but I think that the results will also hold for when this is not the case , i.e. $n_1 \neq n_2$ and $s_1 \neq s_2$.

**Can someone please comment on my mathematical analysis? Have I done this correctly?**

Comment: I'm not going to validate your 'home work'. We are now in the 21st century and I wish that the two-sample t-test (and ANOVA) be taught as an ordinary least squares linear model which then leads to generalised least squares, generalised linear models etc. that can accommodate non-normal data, non-constant variance, serial correlation, autocorrelation and so on. Moreover, testing of assumptions is more appropriately done with the model residuals and not on the raw data. Similarly, I wish that correlation analyses be replaced by regression.

Comment: Many posts already on site discuss these issues at length. Please consider trying the search function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the two samples come from populations with normal distributions, there is a theoretical **guarantee** the test statistic will have the claimed $t$ distribution with the claimed degrees of freedom. When you lack that normality, you no longer get that the test statistic follows such a distribution. In that sense, yes, normality is required for such a test.

However, the test is rather robust to deviations from this normality when sample sizes get large, due to the combination of the central limit theorem and Slutsky's theorem, which I have heard jointly referred to as the converging-together lemma. In that sense, you can still have the test perform close to perfect when the samples are rather non-normal. Your analysis is alluding to this (though I think it misses the part about Slutsky's theorem).

It is possible, perhaps even likely, to be in a situation where the solid robustness is not enough to overcome the gross non-normality. [Glen_b](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/805/glen-b) has a [simulation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/438117/247274) where this happens for a lognormal distribution. It also makes sense when you consider that the robustness comes from convergence theorems that only say what happens in the limit, not in a finite sample.