# Consequences of violation of the normality of the residuals in Linear Rrgression

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, residuals, normality-assumption

I am using linear regression and I see that if there is a violation of the Gauss Markov assumption and the estimates of the parameteres are not unbiased/ efficient. What are the consequences if the residuals are not normally distributed? I read that the p values are no longer reliable but why is that?

Comment: Check out the many threads with the [tag:normality-assumption] that I've added to your question, this has likely been answered multiple times before.

Comment: Much of what I wrote [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/620909/247274) applies. Indeed, the two-sample t-test I discuss there can be thought of as a regression on a binary indicator variable denoting group membership.

Comment: Besides the many good points made in the links above, a general issue is that when the residuals are not symmetric one frequently finds that the model fit is not very good, i.e., predictions will be inaccurate for certain types of observations though predicted means will be OK on the average.  For example, if one should have modeled the reciprocal of Y instead of the original Y values, individual coefficients may be misleading.  This is one reason to use semiparametric models which are Y-transformation invariant.

Comment: Thank ayou. I still have a hard time understanding why if the residuals are not normally disributed then the parameters estimates will not have a t-distribution.

Comment: Technically, the estimates have a t distribution only when the *errors* are Normally distributed (not the residuals, which are *never* iid Normal).  So the issue really is not whether, but *how much,* does a violation of Normality in the errors affect the sampling distribution of the t statistic?  @FrankHarrell points out that asymmetry (really, *skewness*) is the big culprit.

Comment: Point of clarification: why the need to distinguish asymmetry from skewness here?  Thanks.